# Error when Adjacent elements with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am very new with `react-native` and have trouble with this code:

```
  import React, { Component, PropTypes, View } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import StartupActions from '../Redux/StartupRedux'
import ReduxPersist from '../Config/ReduxPersist'

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import WelcomeContainer from '../Containers/WelcomeContainer'
import SettingsContainer from '../Containers/SettingsContainer'
import About from '../Components/About'
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements'



const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Multi Language Sample App' // we advice using something static like your app's name or company name on the startup screen
    }
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})

class RootContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!ReduxPersist.active) {
      this.props.startup()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <AppNavigator />
      <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToDispatch = dispatch => ({
  startup: () => dispatch(StartupActions.startup())
})


export default connect(null, mapStateToDispatch)(RootContainer)

RootContainer.propTypes = {
  startup: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

I get the error : Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

I found different posts with the same issue but was not able to solve my problem.

Comment: View component is from `react-native` not from `react`

Answer (score 1):

Enclose you code inside view or another parent element.

```
render() {
    return (
       <View>
            <AppNavigator />
            <Button
                 large
                 icon={{name: 'envira', type: 'font-awesome'}}
                 title='LARGE WITH RIGHT ICON' />
      </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is View? got an error : Can't find variable: View

Comment: in import of Button add View also

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Answer (score 0):

In react you need to return a single component/element in your render method.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AppNavigator />
        <Button
          large
          icon={{name: 'envira', type: 'font-awesome'}}
          title='LARGE WITH RIGHT ICON'
        />
     </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Since v0.16 of react you can return an array of elements/components. [More info here.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html)

> New render return types: fragments and strings You can now return an
>   array of elements from a component’s render method. Like with other
>   arrays, you’ll need to add a key to each element to avoid the key
>   warning

```
render() {
    return (
        [<AppNavigator />, <Button large icon={{name: 'envira', type: 'font-awesome'}} title='LARGE WITH RIGHT ICON' />]
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error with the second code :  A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: Which implementation you did and whats your react and react-native version?

Comment: The second one, with the first one "View", I got this error : Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: You need to import `View` where your import statements are. If you are having trouble with these steps, please follow tutorials for react and react-native

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.48.4

Comment: Please add relevant code blocks to your question with editing it.